# How to use pandas python3 to get just Middle Initial from Middle name column of CSV and write to new CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I need help.  I have a CSV file that contains names (First, Middle, Last)
I would like to know a way to use pandas to convert Middle Name to just a Middle initial, and save First Name, Middle Init, Last Name to a new csv.

Source CSV

```
First Name,Middle Name,Last Name
Richard,Dale,Leaphart
Jimmy,Waylon,Autry
Willie,Hank,Paisley
Richard,Jason,Timmons
Larry,Josiah,Williams
```

What I need new CSV to look like:

```
First Name,Middle Name,Last Name
Richard,D,Leaphart
Jimmy,W,Autry
Willie,H,Paisley
Richard,J,Timmons
Larry,J,Williams
```

Here is the Python3 code using pandas that I have so far that is reading and writing to a new CSV file.  I just need a some help modifying that one column of each row, saving just the first Character.

```
'''
Read CSV file with First Name, Middle Name, Last Name
Write CSV file with First Name, Middle Initial, Last Name
Print before and after in the terminal to show work was done
'''

import pandas
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

winCsvReadPath = PureWindowsPath("D:\\TestDir\\csv\\test\\original- 
NameList.csv")
originalCsv = Path(winCsvReadPath)

winCsvWritePath= PureWindowsPath("D:\\TestDir\\csv\\test\\modded- 
NameList2.csv")
moddedCsv = Path(winCsvWritePath)

df = pandas.read_csv(originalCsv, index_col='First Name')

df.to_csv(moddedCsv)

df2 = pandas.read_csv(moddedCsv, index_col='First Name')

print(df)
print(df2)
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str` accessor, which allows you to slice strings like you would in normal Python:

```
df['Middle Name'] = df['Middle Name'].str[0]

>>> df
  First Name Middle Name Last Name
0    Richard           D  Leaphart
1      Jimmy           W     Autry
2     Willie           H   Paisley
3    Richard           J   Timmons
4      Larry           J  Williams
```

Comment: Can i then use df.to_csv before the statement you posted, or maybe even assign the result of the statement to another variable, such as 'df2'     Something like df2 = df['Middle Name'] = df['Middle Name'].str[0]  ?

Comment: I think I may just saw error in my commented question, in your answer, df has been already modified by you using the df['MIddle Name'] = part,   so there is no need for a df2 I asked about, and I can also  still use a df.to_csv statement...   Nice, thanks for the quick answer and your expertise!  This resolved my need.

Comment: @S.C.Racer, you can accept the sacul's answer if this helps:

Answer (score 0):

Or Just to another approach with `str.extract`

**Your csv file processing with pandas:**

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep=",")
>>> df
  First Name Middle Name Last Name
0    Richard        Dale  Leaphart
1      Jimmy      Waylon     Autry
2     Willie        Hank   Paisley
3    Richard       Jason   Timmons
4      Larry      Josiah  Williams
```

**Second, Middle Name extraction from the DataFrame:**

assuming all the names starting with first letter with upper case.

```
>>> df['Middle Name'] = df['Middle Name'].str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0})')
 # df['Middle Name'] = df['Middle Name'].str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0})', expand=True)
>>> df
  First Name Middle Name Last Name
0    Richard           D  Leaphart
1      Jimmy           W     Autry
2     Willie           H   Paisley
3    Richard           J   Timmons
4      Larry           J  Williams
```